# how do i filter a list with another list in python

Tags: python, list, filter

Im pretty new to python and essentially i need to filter and get all items in listA that exist in listB.

```
listA = ['cat','dog','cow']

listB = ['sentence 1','sentence 2 contains cat','sentence 3',
         'sentence 4','sentence 5','sentence 6 contains dog']

result = ['sentence 2 contains cat','sentence 6 contains dog']
```

Comment: How did you try to solve this? If you post some code you will get answers faster and better ones.

Answer (score 7):

It can be as simple as this, using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [x for x in listB for a in listA if a in x]
>>> lst
['sentence 2 contains cat', 'sentence 6 contains dog']
```

Edit: This is essentially the same solution as [Ollie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50665319/6655150), but runs ~8-10% faster. For two-way comparison, simply replace `if a in x` with `if (a in x) or (x in a)` (parentheses added for clarity).

Answer (score 2):

For each item in one list, iterate through each item in the other list. For each item, check if it is what you want.

```
listA = ['cat','dog','cow']

listB = ['sentence 1','sentence 2 contains cat','sentence 3','sentence 4','sentence 5','sentence 6 contains dog']

result = []

for itemA in listA:
    for itemB in listB:
        if (itemA in itemB):
            result.append(itemB)
```

Note that this only works one way. If you want to include results where items in `listB` are `in` items in `listA`, then you could use:

```
listA = ['cat','dog','cow']

listB = ['sentence 1','sentence 2 contains cat','sentence 3','sentence 4','sentence 5','sentence 6 contains dog']

result = []

for itemA in listA:
    for itemB in listB:
        if (itemA in itemB):
            result.append(itemB)
        elif (itemB in itemA):
            result.append(itemA)
```